# How make tkinter frame go behind other

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make (self.center = Separator) go behind that only line would be in center, because I need to separate 2 frames, but when I try on small screen those 2 frames are covered by separator or at least make center frame background transparent, if you need full code https://github.com/aurimasjank/Pinger-Alpha/tree/pinger

```
    self.right= Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.right.grid(column=2, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky=N)

    self.probar= Frame(self.tk, bg= "black")
    self.probar.grid(column=0 ,columnspan= 2, row = 2, sticky= E)

    self.center = Separator(self.tk, orient="vertical")
    self.center.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")

    sty = Style(self.center)
    sty.configure("TSeparator", background="#00CC00")

    self.botFrame = Frame(self.tk, bg="black")
    self.botFrame.grid(column=2, row = 2, pady=1, sticky= SE)

    self.colnr = 0
    self.rownrleft = 0
    self.rownrright = 0

    self.titlelbl= Label(self.right, text="Service Status:",bg="black",
                            fg="#00CC00",font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.titlelbl2= Label(self.left, text="GW Status:",bg="black",
                            fg="#00CC00",font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.titlelbl.grid(column=0, row = 0,sticky=N)        
    self.titlelbl2.grid(column=0, row = 0,sticky=N)

    self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self.probar,orient ="horizontal",
                                        length = 410, mode ="determinate")
    self.progress.grid(column=0, row = 0,pady= (20,0))

    self.string = StringVar()
    self.timecount = StringVar()

    self.titlelbl3= Label(self.probar, textvariable= self.string ,
                            bg="black", fg="#00CC00",font=("Helvetica", 24))
    self.titlelbl3.grid(column=0, row = 1)
```

Edit:

So basically what was wrong is that progress bar was expanding column. But there's a new problem how place progressbar in middle of bottom that it wouldn't expand col 1

Comment: which frame is the "middle frame" -- you only have two frames, I don't see one between them.

Comment: self.center = Separator creates like a frame around it self blocking left frame

Comment: the two frames are on different rows, so how do you expect the vertical separator to be between them? Can you provide a picture or ascii drawing of what you expect it to look like?

Comment: So the thig is progress bar was in col 1 ruining everything, I expect : Left frame | seperator | right frame . \n |empty|progressbar|botframe|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is due to the width of column 1 which is determined by the largest widget (I don't think it's the separator here, but the progress bar). I suggest you to put all row 0 widget in one frame so that they won't be impacted by the other wigets width:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

# create a top frame that will contain left, center and right
# and will spread other the 3 columns so that the width of column 1
# does not decrease the width of the left and right frames
top = Frame(root)
top.grid(row=0, columnspan=3, sticky="nswe")
top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

left= Frame(top, bg="blue", width=200, height=100)
left.grid(column=0, row = 0, pady=5 ,padx=10, sticky="n")

center = ttk.Separator(top, orient="vertical")
center.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="ns")

sty = ttk.Style(center)
sty.configure("TSeparator", background="#00CC00")

right= Frame(top, bg="blue", width=200, height=100)
right.grid(column=2, row = 0, pady=5,padx=10, sticky="n")

probar= Frame(root, bg= "black")
probar.grid(column=1, row = 1, sticky= "s")

botFrame = Frame(root, bg="black", width=100, height=50)
botFrame.grid(column=2, row = 1, pady=5, sticky="se")

progress = ttk.Progressbar(probar,orient ="horizontal",
                           length = 410, mode ="determinate")
progress.grid(column=0, row = 0,pady= (20,0))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thats actually it , progress bar who was doing evil, so i jsut putted it to col 0

Comment: but if I want to place progress bar in middle without ruining everything else

Comment: You can put the progressbar alone on one row and use `columnspan=3` in the `grid` method to center it.

Comment: funny when i tried it first time it didn't worked thanks anyway

Comment: try `column=0` in addition to `columnspan=3`.